# Reading SyndicationFeed in ThreadPool.RunAsync

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, threadpool

I'm developing a Windows 8 Metro RSS Feed app. Therefore I'm implementing a Background Task to check if new feeds are available and inform the user if so. I do this as follows:

```
public sealed class UpdateCheck : IBackgroundTask
{
  public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
  {
    BackgroundTaskDeferral backgroundTaskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    await StartUpdateCheck();

    backgroundTaskDeferral.Complete();
  }

  public IAsyncAction StartUpdateCheck()
  {
    return ThreadPool.RunAsync(async o =>
      { 
        SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
        SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri("http://.../feed.xml"));

        ApplicationDataContainer applicationDataContainer = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        string lastFeedId = (string) applicationDataContainer.Values["LastFeedId"];

        if (lastFeedId != feed.Items.First().Id)
        {
          // inform user
        }
      });
  }
}
```

When I'm debugging the code and i want to step over the line `SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri("http://.../feed.xml"));` by hitting F10, nothing happens. The further code lines don't get executed. So, when i set a breakpoint *before* the `RetrieveFeedAsync` method, the breakpoint gets hit. *After* this line, no breakpoint gets hit.

I'm reading the RSS-Feeds on another position in the code, which is not a BackgroundTask (and not in a `ThreadPool.RunAsync` lambda expression) and there everything works fine, so the `ThreadPool.RunAsync` method might causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for ThreadPool.RunAsync in a background task, it already runs in a separate thread.

Comment: Ok, I just removed the `ThreadPool.RunAsync` and I'm still getting the same behavior: breakpoints after the RetriveFeedAsync method don't get hit. So the `ThreadPool.RunAsync` isn't the problem here.

Comment: Have you changed the `IAsyncAction` return type? Just place all the code previously in `ThreadPool.RunAsync` directly to `Run`